# How can I find out the Screen server process?

Tags: gnu-screen, ps, netstat

Does GNU Screen have a server-client architecture model?

Is each Screen session  a Screen client process?

Why can't I  find out the Screen server process, but  only its session processes i.e. client processes? (I suppose both Screen server and client processes contain a substring `screen` in their names up to cases)

```
$ sudo netstat -a | grep -i screen
[sudo] password for t: 
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     2807736  /run/screen/S-testme/3341.testme
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     2809282  /run/screen/S-testme/3875.tm
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     4533106  /run/screen/S-t/27525.test

$ ps aux | grep -i [s]creen
testme    3341  0.0  0.0  45416  2428 ?        Ss   Nov30   0:00 SCREEN -S testme
testme    3875  0.0  0.0  38860  2380 ?        Ss   Nov30   0:00 SCREEN -S tm
t        27525  0.0  0.0  45828  3740 ?        Ss   07:22   0:00 SCREEN -S test
```

How can I find out the Screen server process?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each Screen session is its own “server”; these are the “SCREEN” processes, and they are the processes which continue running when you detach from a session. The “client” is a “screen” process which connects to the corresponding session and allows you to interact with it; these are short-lived (relatively speaking), and only last as long as they are attached to a session.

You can see all your current user’s running sessions with

```
screen -ls
```

This will show the process identifiers, tty and host of all the available sessions.

```
ps -fC screen
```

will show all the running `screen` processes, both sessions and clients.

Comment: Thanks. Does `ps` show the Screen client processes? How can I find out the Screen client processes?

Comment: Ok, I see, when I detach a session, its client process is killed. When I reattach a session, a new client process is created.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo screen -list
```

you can find the screen process Id